# Dajaxice callback function called twice

Tags: python, ajax, django, dajaxice, neo4django

I'm using `django-dajaxice-ng` package (`django-dajaxice` fork for `Django` 1.5 and above, since I use `Django 1.5.4`), and I have this strange issue.
Sometimes the callback function is called twice or even more.
Simple usage:

```
...
{% load dajaxice_templatetags %}
...
{% dajaxice_js_import %}

<script>

    function update_chat(data) {
        messages = eval(data.messages);
        howmany=messages.length;
        if (howmany>0)
            console.log('called');
        for (i=0;i<howmany;i++) {
            M=messages[i];
            console.log(M.msg,M.sent);
        };
    }

    setInterval(function() {
            Dajaxice.myapp.receiveChat(update_chat,{'userID': {{otheruser.id}} });
    },2000);

 </script>
```

and in `myapp/ajax.py`:

```
def receiveChat(request,userID):
    # find new messages from userID and mark them as READ.
    return json.dumps({'messages':serialized_messages})
```

Here's the console log:

```
called
"Message" "16:09:28"
called
"Message" "16:09:28"
```

As you can see, sometimes (very often, actually) `update_chat` is triggered 2 or 3 times.
I'm 100% sure that:

- the ajax function receiveChat is called once
- the message shown twice is stored once.

I define `serialized_messages = json.dumps(messages)`, being `messages` a list of dicts.
The result is like this:

```
'[{"msg": "Message", "sent": "16:09:28"}]'
```

In this case there's one only message, but works as well with more than one.

I had to do this double serialization (the other one's in `return`) because apparently dajaxice accept only dict as admitted return values.

Anyone who also got this behavior? Any clue?

**EDIT**
I'm using `neo4django` which uses `neo4j-rest-client`, I have to do a .save() on a model, and notice ONLY with that save I got the problem, maybe because of another HTTP request?

**EDIT 2**
It's *not* a dajaxice issue, switching to ajax `$.get()` gives same results, but really I can't figure it out. Seems like not all browsers are doing it, sure Chrome does.

Comment: have you checked whether your `sendChat` function is called more than once?

Comment: Yep, and no ;) that function is the one storing the message, and as I wrote, it's stored once because the function is called once. 100% sure is the callback.

Comment: maybe posting much of the js would help to figure this out. i never experienced such behavior with django-dajaxice.

Comment: Actually I edited the question because the relevant part was not in SENDING, but RECEIVING the messages.

Comment: Added javascript code (for debugging I'm simply showing chat messages in console.log).

Comment: I edited at the end: there's an additional HTTP request being done. So what is happpening that makes dajaxice trigger callback twice?